Does a group always have subgroups of order, order of its quotient groups?

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $n$ and let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ of order $d$ $(1<d<n)$. Does there exist a subgroup $H'$ such that order of $H'$ is $n/d$, the index of $H$ in $G$.

This is not the same problem as the one asked here.
Here $H$ is necessarily normal.
Now my guess is that this is not true. But I can't think of a counterexample. In order to produce a counter example I need to choose $G$ and $H$ such that:

$G$ is not abelian.
$G$ is not simple. Moreover, $H$ is not the only normal subgroup of $G$.
$n/d$ must not be prime.
gcd$(d,n/d)≠1$ (due to Schur–Zassenhaus theorem).

Keeping these in check, I'm unable think of a counterexample. Maybe it's true. Please help.
This is not a book exercise. It struck me while thinking about this other problem: If there is a homomorphism of $G$ onto $G'$, does $G$ have a subgroup isomorphic to $G'$? The answer is no here; $Q_8/Z(Q_8)$ is not isomorphic to any subgroup of $Q_8$. But my question is: Does $G$ have a subgroup of order $o(G')$?

Why should $G$ be non-simple? The group $G = A_5$ produces a counterexample. Since its order is $60$, it contains a subgroup $H$ of order $2$. However, $A_5$ cannot contain a subgroup of order $30$, since such a subgroup would be of index $2$, hence normal. But $A_5$ is simple.

@Marktmeister Because the subgroup $H$ of order 2 in $A_5$ is not normal.

Oh, right - I misread and did not see that you required $H$ to be normal. My bad.

As you expected, the statment is wrong. The group $\mathrm{SL}(2,3)$ of order $24$ contains a normal subgroup of order $2$, namely its center (generated by $-I_2$). However, $\mathrm{SL}(2,3)$ does not contain a subgroup of order $12$. (See for instance here.)

Thank you so much!
